# How can I insert an image into SQL Server which come as an argument?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, json

I am working on an app which uses jsonservice (RESTful web service) for backend database process and Andriod as front end. I just need to insert an image into database which is sent as an argument through the jsonservice.

Example:

```
public bool register(string name,string address, string image)
{

}
```

Comment: don't insert images into databases.

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: Refer this link http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource21-How-to-store-and-retrieve-images-from-SQL-server-database-using-aspnet.aspx.aspx

Comment: sir, I am doing webservice using Json(RESTfull webservice) for the app, my colleague works on android to develop its front-end.  we have a registration form which include an image to insert. pls suggest me a better way to insert and retrieve the image.

Comment: are you using "varbinary" datatype in your table ?

Comment: I strongly agree with @e4c5,as he said do not enter image direct to db instead of that enter only it's physical path.

Comment: There is always the blob if you really wanna store the image in the db, but as the guys has said its not recommended.

Comment: I disagree inserting images into dbs has its advantages. well convert your image into a byte stream and then convert it to string. the data type required to store binary data in db is VARBINARY. after receiving at service convert back into byte stream and insert into db